# How to Insert an image into a Word Document using PHP?

Tags: php, ms-word

Is there any Microsoft Word document manipulation library that allows to open an already created Word Document and insert an external image into it? Neither phpoffice/phpword nor PHPWord seem to be able to handle the task.

Comment: What problem are you having with PHPWord? It should be quite capable of doing what you need

Comment: And note that phpoffice/phpword is the official repo for PHPWord

Comment: Could you share a snippet or the documentation URL where we could find an example of how to do it? We haven't been able to find a working example and we did find a bug indicating it was not possible.

Comment: What problem are you having? Can you read the existing Word document? Are you having problems inserting the image? Is your issue with saving the document again?

Comment: This is the open issue: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/260

Comment: [Example for Reading](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_11_ReadWord2007.php)

Comment: [Example for adding an image](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_13_Images.php)

Comment: The example shows how to create it from scratch. Is there any way to replace an image inside an already created file? Is it just a matter of opening the file and working on it instead of creating it from scratch?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91622/discussion-between-rreyes1979-and-mark-baker).

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018003/how-to-add-set-images-on-phpoffice-phpword-template

Answer (score 2):

OK, based on @Mark Baker's answer. I created a sub class, that way there is no need to overwrite the original TemplateProcessor.

```
<?php
class TemplateProcessor extends \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor
{
    /**
     * Content of document rels (in XML format) of the temporary document.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $temporaryDocumentRels;

    public function __construct($documentTemplate)
    {
        parent::__construct($documentTemplate);
        $this->temporaryDocumentRels = $this->zipClass->getFromName('word/_rels/document.xml.rels');
    }

    /**
     * Set a new image
     *
     * @param string $search
     * @param string $replace
     */
    public function setImageValue($search, $replace){
        // Sanity check
        if (!file_exists($replace)) {
            throw new \Exception("Image not found at:'$replace'");
        }

        // Delete current image
        $this->zipClass->deleteName('word/media/' . $search);

        // Add a new one
        $this->zipClass->addFile($replace, 'word/media/' . $search);
    }

    /**
     * Search for the labeled image's rId
     *
     * @param string $search
     */
    public function seachImagerId($search){
        if (substr($search, 0, 2) !== '${' && substr($search, -1) !== '}') {
            $search = '${' . $search . '}';
        }
        $tagPos = strpos($this->temporaryDocumentRels, $search);
        $rIdStart = strpos($this->temporaryDocumentRels, 'r:embed="',$tagPos)+9;
        $rId=strstr(substr($this->temporaryDocumentRels, $rIdStart),'"', true);
        return $rId;
    }

    /**
     * Get img filename with it's rId
     *
     * @param string $rId
     */
    public function getImgFileName($rId){
        $tagPos = strpos($this->temporaryDocumentRels, $rId);
        $fileNameStart = strpos($this->temporaryDocumentRels, 'Target="media/',$tagPos)+14;
        $fileName=strstr(substr($this->temporaryDocumentRels, $fileNameStart),'"', true);
        return $fileName;
    }

    public function setImageValueAlt($searchAlt, $replace)
    {
        $this->setImageValue($this->getImgFileName($this->seachImagerId($searchAlt)),$replace);
    }
}
```

This way I had only to do

```
<?php
$template = new TemplateProcessor('path/to/my/template.docx');
$template->setImageValueAlt('myPicturePlacehoder', '/tmp/pictureToReplace.png');
```