# How can i add a picture in phpword with template processor?

Tags: php, docx, phpword

Ok so I finally got phpword template processor working and now I am having a small problem: I would like to dynamically add a picture to my template. So far I have been replacing things in my template like this:

```
$templateProcessor->setValue('name', 'MY NAME COMES HERE');

$templateProcessor->setValue('name2', 'OWW YEA PHPWORD IS WONDERFUL');
```

How can I get an image replaced?? Any help will be much and greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is not supported in the current PhpWord (0.13.0). You can find some discussion here https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/260 and some work-arounds here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018003/how-to-add-set-images-on-phpoffice-phpword-template

Comment: thanks @ejuhjav I will check it out.