# Phpword - add image with template processor

Tags: php, phpword

I do understand this is a duplicate question, but none of the answers seem to work, perhaps I'm not using the correct version of phpword relevant to the answers.

[How to add/set images on PHPOffice/PHPWord Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018003/how-to-add-set-images-on-phpoffice-phpword-template)

So I've tried precisely editing my templateprocessor.php file, using the code in the above link, but I get error after error.

Please can somebody assist with a workable solution to add images using the template processor in phpword.

Answer (score 0):

Image replacements are supported in version 0.16.0:
https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/stable/templates-processing.html#setimagevalue

Comment: Why was this ever downvoted? It works perfectly and is a much better solution than the one linked in the question.