# PHPWord : Is it possible to replace placeholder text in a document with an image (at the same position where the text was)?

Tags: php, phpword, electronic-signature

As part of the implementation of an electronic signature function. I need to add the signature at a specific position in the Word document. The position however could vary from one document to another. The only potential solution to this seems to be having a signature placeholder which gets replaced with the signature.png once the document is signed.

Is this possible with the PHPWord package ? If not is there any package out there that can do this ?

Comment: Never worked with PHPword, but according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018003/how-to-add-set-images-on-phpoffice-phpword-template)  you can replace an image source. So perhaps add an image to the template (could be a 1x1 blank .png) and replace the source later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to do it with phpword, as per their [documentation](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html) :

First, the word file needs to have a placeholder :

```
${CompanyLogo}
${UserLogo:50:50} ${Name} - ${City} - ${Street}
${Signature:50:50}
```

Then with php, we can replace the placeholder like so :

```
$templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor('Template.docx');
$templateProcessor->setValue('Name', 'John Doe');
$templateProcessor->setValue(array('City', 'Street'), array('Detroit', '12th Street'));

$templateProcessor->setImageValue('CompanyLogo', 'path/to/company/logo.png');
$templateProcessor->setImageValue('UserLogo', array('path' => 'path/to/logo.png', 'width' => 100, 'height' => 100, 'ratio' => false));
$templateProcessor->setImageValue('Signature', function () {
    // Closure will only be executed if the replacement tag is found in the template
    return array('path' => 'path/to/signature.png', 'width' => 100, 'height' => 100, 'ratio' => false);
});
```